# there is a large circle around my object in blender 2.91

Tags: modeling

I created an object in blender, and not knowing what i pressed now there is a large circle around my object which i can't seem to select in edit mode or remove (without removing the original base object). Im really new to blender and this is mildly annoying as i cant seem to find an online solution. (others seemed to have switched off proportional editing to solve this but doesn't seem to be the problem here)

[image: screenshot of screen]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Go into edit mode with Tab, and you will most likely see that you have a ring of edges there. You can delete it

Comment: There is a chance you have chosen face select type in edit mode? Change to vertex of edge select mode to select the ring.

Answer (score 0):

Go to where the proportion editor is where the global and local options are at the top of ur screen and turn it off.[image]

Comment: Maybe reconsider this one. ... You can see from the screenshot in the question that Proportional Editing isn't turned on, so this isn't the problem?